# NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined when running tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I run python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py with Tensorflow 1.9 of CPU version and Python 3.6 under Ubuntu system, there is NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined, does someone know why this happens and how to deal with it? Thanks. Here is the guide i follow.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 311, in test_create_ssd_resnet_v1_fpn_model_from_config
    model = model_builder.build(model_proto, is_training=True)
  File "/home/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 110, in build
    add_background_class)
  File "/home/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 214, in _build_ssd_model
    ssd_config.anchor_generator)
  File "/home/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/anchor_generator_builder.py", line 91, in build
    cfg.normalize_coordinates
  File "/home/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/multiscale_grid_anchor_generator.py", line 61, in __init__
    for scale in xrange(scales_per_octave)]
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

Comment: xrange doesnt exist on python 3. Use range

Comment: @joaquin Worth noting that range doesn't exist in python 2 so xrange should be used if the OP ever needs to use it in a version of python which is earlier than python 3

Comment: @Adi219 He is using Python 3.6 as declared in the post

Comment: @joaquin I know, which is why I said that it's 'worth noting' :) (as it's still useful information for users who stumble upon this question)

Comment: @Adi219 `range` _does_ exist in Python 2, it returns a list instead of a generator.

Comment: @xdurch0 I've been misinformed :(

Comment: @Adi219 This is wrong.  range and xrange exist in python 2. xrange was renamed to range() in Python 3.x, and the original range() function was deprecated in Python 3.x.

Comment: @joaquin I've been misinformed, as I just told xdurch0 above when they told me the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks for all your helps. I added xrange = range in the code of Python files Traceback (most recent call last), it works right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`xrange()` was removed from `python3` and was replaced by `range()`. Use `range()` instead (it works exactly the same as `xrange()`).**

However, if you need to use the `range()` function in `python2` (which you don't in this case), use `xrange()` as `range()` returns a list instead of a generator (as @xdurch0 says in the comments).

Comment: Please can (potential) downvoters explain why they're downvoting?